# Ultra Long Range (200-500km) Arduino Communication using a Gibson Girl

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, communication, wireless, rf

I came across this article on Hackaday showing a simple AM transmitter sending a morse code tone 700km!

I'm looking into a EPIRB for myself while deep in the bush / outback hunting or camping, just to send a message to my wife. (a true EPIRB wouldn't be useful to let her know I'm all good, or ask her to call my mate to come pull my truck out of a bog hole)

I plan on sending short text messages via Morse Code, or probably just 8 bit ascii - so speed is not important. If a 50 character message takes 5 minutes to send - so be it... It's meant for check ins, not rapid messaging.

I'll take care of the screen and keyboard side of it - but just interested if anyone has any thoughts or experience using a long range AM signal generator like in the link, and interfacing an Arduino as a transceiver...

https://hackaday.com/2014/12/19/gibson-girl-emergency-beacon-built-from-a-wind-up-flashlight/

Comment: 40 meters is considered one of the most reliable all-season long distance communication (DX) bands.  7.023 MHz  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Oicqr28xLk  you may need a directional coupler or VSWR meter to trim each 20m wire length for best results

Comment: SPOT Gen3 Satellite GPS Tracker can have you send a message that all is okay, besides calling in an SOS. But it can only send a single type of message, so it's can send any arbitrary text. You could agree with your wife to some message schema, like regular "I'm okay" message will only be send at 20:00h. All other times mean, that I would require some non-emergency help.

Comment: Not sure if I would trust my life on a self made AM transmitter. But as an addition would be a good idea. Depending on your location you might need to have a license to transmit (HAM-license in the USA).